# Trying to add image to email get ckeditor error

Tags: civimail, ckeditor

Using CiviCRM 5.36.1 - trying to create email to send using civimail.
at:
.../wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fa%2F#/mailing/336

Previously had no trouble adding an image by clicking on the add image icon.
Now get error when trying to either upload a new image, or linking to an existing image.

Get "incorrect server response" as shown below.

The web console shows:
[CKEDITOR] Error code: filetools-response-error.
Object { responseText: "
\n**Deprecated**: The each() function is deprecated.

I removed old images from
/public_html/wp/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/persist/contribute/images
and still get same error.

Any suggestions?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it is just a coincidence, but after I upgraded the version of php my site uses from 7.3.33 to 7.4.27 I am again able to add images to a draft email.

Answer (score 1):

A nice workaround for this is to install the CKEditor5 Extension (https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/ckeditor5) and follow its setup instructions. Most of the Drupal 9 installs I use, have this problem and it is solved with this.